# Bash: detect execute vs source in a script?

Tags: bash

I have a script that is littered around my filesystem (side effect of a build process) that sets some global environment variables (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, ROOTDIR, etc) that need to be in my shell for proper operation.  Of course, that means I need to `source script.sh` or `. script.sh` to get it to work, and not `./script.sh` (which would spawn a new shell and not set the variables in my current shell).

Is there anything I can add to the script to *prevent* (or warn) someone running `./script.sh` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In a shell script, `$0` is the name of the currently running script.  You can use this to tell if you're being sourced or run like this:

```
if [[ "$(basename -- "$0")" == "script.sh" ]]; then
    >&2 echo "Don't run $0, source it"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: (Mac) Didn't work, when I ran script from cmd line ( `bash script.sh` vs `source script.sh`)

Answer (score 19):

Simplest way in `bash` is:

```
if [ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]; then
    echo "Error: Script must be sourced"
    exit 1
fi
```

`$BASH_SOURCE` always contains the name/path of the script.

`$0` only contains the name/path of the script when NOT sourced.

So when they match, that means the script was NOT sourced.

Comment: `$0 only contains the name/path of the script when NOT sourced.` Cannot verify this on Mac.

Comment: However, it worked. (Mac) It seems that `BASH_SOURCE` is empty when sourced.

Answer (score 4):

This has been discussed [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced). The [most-upvoted answer by @barroyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706745/1587329) says to use

```
[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" != "${0}" ]] && echo "script ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} is being sourced ..."
```

Comment: @will: [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) says: An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array variable are defined. How a function?

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to remove execute permissions. In that case it can not be executed but it can still be sourced.

Comment: This is incomplete.  You can still run scripts with `bash script` regardless of the execute flag on a script.  Also under Cygwin (does this count?) you cannot take away execute flags.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom interpreter `source_reminder`:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" "Source me!" >&2
exit 1
```

Don't forget to make it executable. Then just use it in your script:

```
#!/path/to/your/source_reminder
foo
bar
whatever
```

Now if you run the script without sourcing, the reminder will do its job.

Comment: Nice catch.  `#!/bin/echo do not execute` or `#!/bin/false` or `#!/usr/bin/awk BEGIN { print "you must source " ARGV[1]; exit(1) }`.  However this does not catch the case where the script is executed with something like `sh script` (as this ignores the Shebang).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to check $0 ([Mikel](https://superuser.com/users/15334/mikel) answer) may be useful to change extension from .sh to .src, for example. It will help to understand anybody that should not execute this script.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound dumb, but if NOTHING should execute it, you can typically just `chmod a-x script.sh` and any attempts to execute it will fail, though not with a friendly warning message like has been suggested in other answers.